# rvm installation: is_a_function: command not found

Tags: ruby, macos, osx-lion, rvm

After installing rvm, using the following:

```
$ curl -s https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer > rvm-installer
$ bash rvm-installer
```

I did the following as advised in the rvm site:

```
$ echo '[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function' >> ~/.bash_profile
$ source .bash_profile 
-sh: is_a_function: command not found
```

When I looked up the installation output, I see that this error has been reported during the installation too (though I also see: "Installation of RVM to /Users//.rvm/ is complete.")

I looked up the rvm scripts and I am able to see the function is_a_function in utility script.

Please advise on what I need to do now to fix this.

P.S.: I had to download the installer locally since I kept getting the following error:

```
$ bash < <(curl -s https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer)
-sh: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
```

Comment: That `"Installation of RVM to /Users//.rvm/ is complete."` line looks a little wrong.  Where did rvm actually get installed to?  And you should add the `[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"...` bit to your .bashrc file (so that way it gets invoked each time you start BASH, instead of having to explicitly call it from the command line).

Comment: Hi Michael, Thanks for the reply. It actually gave the output as: /Users/[my_user_name]/.rvm/ Don't know why that got removed.
I added the lines to .bash.profile as mentioned in rvm notes. (see right end of the command line) I don't think the issue is with the destination of the command. It is about the availability of the function is_a_function().

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was getting the same error, but switching to stable version seems to have fixed it.

Did work:

```
sudo bash -s stable < <(curl -s https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer)
```

Comment: $ sudo bash -s stable < <(curl -s https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer)
-sh: syntax error near unexpected token `<'

Comment: A slight change solved it. But the root cause seems to be the "-s stable":

$ curl -s https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer | bash -s stable

Comment: How does this work? I don't really see how adding "stable" there would change what curl downloads?

Comment: Stable version gave me this error: "-bash: sudo: command not found"